# Semantic UI form onSuccess event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, semantic-ui

I've made a form using semantic UI. The form validation works perfectly. But the onSuccess event isn't getting triggered when I click the submit button.

```
    formValidationRules = {
          //some rules
    }

    var formSettings = {
        on: 'blur',
        inline: true,
        onSuccess : function() {
            alert("success");
            return true;
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.ui.form').form(formValidationRules, formSettings);
    });
```

This is the example I find on all web searches. Any ideas?

The full form code is [here](http://pastebin.com/kp6vm3v1).

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out, running across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to include all the settings in the same object, at least that's the way I do it. Try combining `formValidationRules` and `formSettings`.